# current date in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, logstash

I have a problem with the query in jdbc logstash.: `z.clock < to_unix_timestamp(sysdate)-10 seconds`

how to save system date minus 10 seconds?

z.clock is Unix timestamp.

```
SELECT h.name as hostname,i.name as item,i.key_,z.clock,z.value FROM zabbix.hosts h where z.clock > :sql_last_value and z.clock < to_unix_timestamp(sysdate)-10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, one option is to subract it as

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate as right_now,
  2         sysdate - 10 / (24 * 60 * 60) as ten_seconds_ago,
  3         sysdate - interval '10' second ten_seconds_ago_2
  4  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           TEN_SECONDS_AGO     TEN_SECONDS_AGO_2
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
31.07.2019 11:16:07 31.07.2019 11:15:57 31.07.2019 11:15:57

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
select sysdate - interval '10' second
from dual
```

For example:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate - interval '10' second, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as d_minus_10,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as d
  3  from dual;

D_MINUS_10          D
------------------- -------------------
31/07/2019 11:18:46 31/07/2019 11:18:56
```

Comment: From you code, you already have a function to convert the format and your issue is in subtracting 10 seconds from sysdate. If your question is different, please edit to question to better explain your need. As is, the question already has answers in the linked questions

Comment: In your code you use the function to_unix_timestamp and ask "how to save system date minus 10 seconds?". So, IMHO, you have a function that converts date in unix format and you need to subtract 10 seconds from a date. If your question is different, please edit it (or post a new one) to better explain your need, possibly adding some sample data and needed result.